# Python Script To Loop Through All of the Switches and Interfaces and Pull Info and Output into a CSV?

Tags: python, automation, scripting

I am pretty new to Python and such so please bear with me. I am tasked with creating a python script that loops through all of the switches and all of the interfaces and pulls the interface stats and outputs them into a CSV. Switch, interface, state, giants, crc, input errors, output errors, input packets, input bytes, output packets, output bytes? I know as of right now there is nothing in script for the giants and crc and such, which I need to figure out how to do, but this is just of where I'm at now trying to get this script to run as is.

I think I have found a script similar online, but am struggling with the troubleshooting. I get several errors, such as:

- "AttributeError" 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" @ Line
- "IndexError: list index out of range"
- "NameError: name 'regex_memory' is not defined.

Code --->

> 

```
import netmiko
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netmiko.exceptions import NetMikoTimeoutException
from netmiko.exceptions import SSHException
from netmiko.exceptions import AuthenticationException

import re

#here is list of infrastructure switch ip addresses
ip_list = ['xx.xx.xx.xx', 'xx.xx.xx.xx'.....] 

#list where informations will be stored
devices = []

#clearing the old data from the CSV file and writing the headers
f = open("IOS.csv", "w+")
f.write("IP Address, Hostname, Uptime, Current_Version, Current_Image, Serial_Number, Device_Model, Device_Memory")
f.write("\n")
f.close()

#clearing the old data from the CSV file and writing the headers
f = open("login_issues.csv", "w+")
f.write("IP Address, Status")
f.write("\n")
f.close()



#loop all ip addresses in ip_list
for ip in ip_list:
    cisco = {
        'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
        'ip': ip,
        'username': 'xxx', #ssh username
    'password': 'xxx', #ssh password
    'secret': 'xxx', #ssh_enable_password
    'ssh_strict': False,
        'fast_cli': False,
    }

    #handling exceptions errors

    try:
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco)
    except NetMikoTimeoutException:
        f = open("login_issues.csv", "a")
        f.write(ip + "," + "Device Unreachable/SSH not enabled")
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
        continue
    except AuthenticationException:
        f = open("login_issues.csv", "a")
        f.write(ip + "," + "Authentication Failure")
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
        continue
    except SSHException:
        f = open("login_issues.csv", "a")
        f.write(ip + "," + "SSH not enabled")
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
        continue

    try:
        net_connect.enable()

    #handling exceptions errors        
    except ValueError:
        f = open("login_issues.csv", "a")
        f.write(ip + "," + "Could be SSH Enable Password issue")
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
        continue
        

    #execute show version on router and save output to output object
    sh_ver_output = net_connect.send_command('show version')
    ###Below are show int, MAC address-table, and ip arp for task###
    #sh_int_output = net_connect.send_command('show int')
    #sh_macTable_output = net_connect.send_command('show mac address-table')
    #sh_arpTable_output = net_connect.send_command('show ip arp')

    #finding hostname in output using regular expressions
    regex_hostname = re.compile(r'(\S+)\suptime')
    hostname = regex_hostname.findall(sh_ver_output)

    #finding uptime in output using regular expressions
    regex_uptime = re.compile(r'\S+\suptime\sis\s(.+)')
    uptime = regex_uptime.findall(sh_ver_output)
    uptime = str(uptime).replace(',', '').replace("'", "")
    uptime = str(uptime)[1: -1]


    #finding version in output using regular expressions
    regex_version = re.compile(r'Cisco\sIOS\sSoftware.+Version\s([^ ,]+)')
    version = regex_version.findall(sh_ver_output)

    #finding serial in output using regular expressions
    regex_serial = re.compile(r'Processor\sboard\sID\s(\S+)')
    serial = regex_serial.findall(sh_ver_output)

    #finding ios image in output using regular expressions
    regex_ios = re.compile(r'System\simage\sfile\sis\s"([^ "]+)')
    ios = regex_ios.findall(sh_ver_output)

    #finding model in output using regular expressions
    regex_model = re.compile(r'[Cc]isco\s(\S+).*memory.')
    model = regex_model.findall(sh_ver_output)


    #finding the router's memory using regular expressions
    regex_memory = re.search(r'with (.*?) bytes of memory', sh_ver_output).group(1)
    memory = regex_memory


    #append results to table[hostname, uptime, version, serial, ios, model]
    devices.append([ip, hostname[0], uptime, version[0], ios[0], serial[0], model[0], memory])



    #print all results(for all routers) on screen
    for i in devices:
        i = ", ".join(i)
        f = open("IOS.csv", "a")
        f.write(i)
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
```

I have tried to comment out blocks of the regex functions but issues persist with each one I don't comment out. Tried to figure out the AttributeException error with 'group', kinda lost on that one. Overall, I took an intro course to Java 3-4 years ago and would love and greatly appreciate some assistance

Answer (score 0):

so with multiple errors, you need to go at it step by step.

Fix one issue, go to next issue, fix that, etc

The code you found is likely quite old, as the file handling is quite horrible. Since I don't have a cisco router, I can only provide partial assistance, but the code below is fixed at least for the file handling.

It will print out the response that the "show_version" command outputs.

You'll then need to make sure that the regex you have matches what you actually expect. Then dump the output in something like [regex101](https://regex101.com) (in the test string section) and find a regex that finds the parts you need. Note that simple python string splitting is likely easier.

I advise you to update your question with the output of a single `sh_ver_output = net_connect.send_command('show version')` so the community actually has some data to work with...

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netmiko.exceptions import NetMikoTimeoutException
from netmiko.exceptions import SSHException
from netmiko.exceptions import AuthenticationException
import re


#here is list of infrastructure switch ip addresses
ip_list = ['xx.xx.xx.xx', 'xx.xx.xx.xx'] 

#list where informations will be stored
devices = []

#clearing the old data from the CSV file and writing the headers
with open("IOS.csv", "w+") as f:
    f.write("IP Address,Hostname,Uptime,Current_Version,Current_Image,Serial_Number,Device_Model,Device_Memory\n")

#clearing the old data from the CSV file and writing the headers
with open("login_issues.csv", "w+") as f:
    f.write("IP Address,Status\n")



#loop all ip addresses in ip_list
for ip in ip_list:
    cisco = {
        'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
        'ip': ip,
        'username': 'xxx', #ssh username
        'password': 'xxx', #ssh password
        'secret': 'xxx', #ssh_enable_password
        'ssh_strict': False,
        'fast_cli': False,
    }

    #handling exceptions errors

    try:
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco)
    except NetMikoTimeoutException:
        with open("login_issues.csv", "a") as f:
            f.write(f"{ip},Device Unreachable/SSH not enabled\n")
        continue
    except AuthenticationException:
        with open("login_issues.csv", "a") as f:
            f.write(f"{ip},Authentication Failure\n")
        continue
    except SSHException:
        with open("login_issues.csv", "a") as f:
            f.write(f"{ip},SSH not enabled\n")
        continue
    try:
        net_connect.enable()
    #handling exceptions errors        
    except ValueError:
        with open("login_issues.csv", "a") as f:
            f.write(f"{ip},Could be SSH Enable Password issue\n")
        continue
        

    #execute show version on router and save output to output object
    sh_ver_output = net_connect.send_command('show version')
    print(f"-----\n{sh_ver_output}\n")
```